# List of tables hangs on the second run

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, errors

I am using my university's template for my thesis available at: http://www.grad.ucalgary.ca/current/thesis/templates/latex-template (similar to http://www.github.com/markwgirard/ucalgarythesis). It shows the tables on the first run, but it hangs  on the second run when I want to get the list of tables. Here is an example with only two tables.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ucalgthes1}% similar to github.com/markwgirard/ucalgarythesis
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1in, bottom= 1in, left= 1in, right= 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, tikz, comment, graphicx, float, tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, rotating, lipsum, setspace, mathptmx, hyperref, changepage}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\begin{document}


\begin{singlespace}
\newpage
\phantomsection
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{List of Tables}
  \cleardoublepage\phantomsection
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}  
\listoftables
\pagestyle{plain}
\newpage
\end{singlespace}



\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption{ \centering Change in Yearly Average Pollution Because of the Progressive Income Tax (1980-2015) \label{fittedvalues}}
%\hspace*{1cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Non-Revenue Neutral Case}}
  \\
\midrule
\midrule
\textbf{Pollutant} &
  \textbf{$PM_{10}$} &
  \textbf{$VOC$} &
  \textbf{$SO_{2}$} &
  \textbf{$NO_{x}$} &
  \textbf{$CO$}
  \\
\midrule
\textbf{Change in pollution (pounds)} &
  -27,564 &
  -48,140&
  -218,721 &
  -137,049&
  -113,296
  \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Using TAXSIM - Revenue Neutral Case}}
  \\
\midrule
\midrule
\textbf{Pollutant} &
  \textbf{$PM_{10}$} &
  \textbf{$VOC$} &
  \textbf{$SO_{2}$} &
  \textbf{$NO_{x}$} &
  \textbf{$CO$}
  \\
\midrule
\textbf{Change in pollution (pounds)} &
    113,244 &
  205,341 &
  989,995 &
  623,530 &
  521,821
  \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\vspace{2mm}
 \raggedright \\

\end{table}


\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Estimation Results For $PM_{10}$-(1980-2015) \label{tab:traffic}}
\scriptsize
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\hspace{-2in}
\begin{center}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{cc}}
\hline
                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{OLS}          \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
                &(1)             &(2)             \\
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{income after tax}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{income before tax}\\
\hline
Income before tax ($ 10000)&       0.3518***&                \\
                &     (0.0068)   &                \\

\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{center}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-0pt}
\label{pm10}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

I should have a list of tables for my thesis and I must `useucalgthes1` . I really appreciate any help!

Thanks

Comment: By "hangs out" do you mean stops with errors?  Your sample code doesn't compile for various reasons.

Comment: Yes, I mean it does not compile after the first time.

Comment: Unfortunately this class is a disaster.

Comment: I would abandon this class completely and use the github linked version instead. You don't *have* to use the class, you just have to format your thesis according to the university guidelines (which seem fairly straightforward.)  You will save yourself time fixing any small issues with the linked class than the major issues you will encounter using the "official" class.

Comment: Thanks @Alan Munn, but I have the same problem when I change the document class to`ucalgarythesis`in the above example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a cleaned up version of your document using the linked class:

I've changed some things.

- added the `caption` package to format captions. Don't put formatting commands directly into your `\captions`
- replaced `mathptmx` with `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` (more up-to-date)
- added `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to get the font encoding correct
- moved `\usepackage{hyperref}` to load last (usually a good idea)
- removed `setspace` (loaded by the class)
- added a `\captionsetup` command to centre captions

I've also put each package into its own `\usepackage` command. This allows you to add package options more easily, and generally makes it clearer what packages you are using.

I've also removed the `[H]` specification from your tables. Although there are sometimes uses for this, it's generally not required; TeX will place your tables and figures for you.  If you need to place something at a specific place, don't use a `table` or `figure` environment, and use `\captionof` to add the caption.

You might also want to use the `siunitx` package for formatting tables with numerical data. It has numerous facilities to format numbers correctly in tables.

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdfLaTeX
\documentclass[12pt]{ucalgarythesis}% from to github.com/markwgirard/ucalgarythesis
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % added
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % replacing mathptmx
\usepackage{caption} % for formatting captions properly
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{hyperref} % should be loaded last usually

\captionsetup{justification=centering}


\begin{document}


\begin{singlespace}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
\end{singlespace}
\newpage

\begin{table}[htpb]
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption{ Change in Yearly Average Pollution Because of the Progressive Income Tax (1980-2015) \label{fittedvalues}}
%\hspace*{1cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Non-Revenue Neutral Case}}
  \\
\midrule
\midrule
\textbf{Pollutant} &
  \textbf{$PM_{10}$} &
  \textbf{$VOC$} &
  \textbf{$SO_{2}$} &
  \textbf{$NO_{x}$} &
  \textbf{$CO$}
  \\
\midrule
\textbf{Change in pollution (pounds)} &
  -27,564 &
  -48,140&
  -218,721 &
  -137,049&
  -113,296
  \\
\multicolumn{6}{c}{\textbf{Using TAXSIM - Revenue Neutral Case}}
  \\
\midrule
\midrule
\textbf{Pollutant} &
  \textbf{$PM_{10}$} &
  \textbf{$VOC$} &
  \textbf{$SO_{2}$} &
  \textbf{$NO_{x}$} &
  \textbf{$CO$}
  \\
\midrule
\textbf{Change in pollution (pounds)} &
    113,244 &
  205,341 &
  989,995 &
  623,530 &
  521,821
  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}

%\vspace{2mm}
%\raggedright

\begin{table}[htpb]
\caption{Estimation Results For $PM_{10}$-(1980-2015) \label{tab:traffic}}
\scriptsize
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\hspace{-2in}
\begin{center}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{cc}}
\hline
                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{OLS}          \\\cmidrule(lr){2-3}
                &(1)             &(2)             \\
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{income after tax}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{income before tax}\\
\hline
Income before tax (\$ 10000)&       0.3518***&                \\
                &     (0.0068)   &                \\

\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{center}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-0pt}
\label{pm10}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```